# What's the difference between assigning an event watcher and setting the onclick?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have noticed that javascript is behaving differently in these two scenarios, and I'd like to understand why.

With a link and script like this:

```
<a class="delete-link" href="@Url.Action("_CustomFieldDelete", new {id = item.CustomFieldId})">Delete</a>

//... In my script.js file.
$(function () {
    $("a.delete-link").click(function () {
        var deleteLink = $(this);
        deleteLink.hide();
        var confirmButton = deleteLink.siblings(".delete-confirm");
        confirmButton.show();

        var cancelDelete = function () {
            removeEvents();
            showDeleteLink();
        };

        var deleteItem = function () {
            removeEvents();
            confirmButton.hide();
            var url = '/' + confirmButton.attr('data-delete-controller') + '/' + confirmButton.attr('data-delete-action') + '/' + confirmButton.attr('data-        delete-id');
            $.post(
                url,
                AddAntiForgeryToken({ id: confirmButton.attr('data-delete-id') }))
               .done(function () {
                   var parentRow = deleteLink.parents("tr:first");
                   parentRow.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                       parentRow.remove();
                   });
               }).fail(function (data) {
                   alert("error");
               });
            return false;
        };

        var removeEvents = function () {
            confirmButton.off("click", deleteItem);
            $(document).on("click", cancelDelete);
            $(document).off("keypress", onKeyPress);
        };

        var showDeleteLink = function () {
            confirmButton.hide();
            deleteLink.show();
        };

        var onKeyPress = function (e) {
            //Cancel if escape key pressed
            if (e.which == 27) {
                cancelDelete();
            }
        };

        confirmButton.on("click", deleteItem);
        $(document).on("click", cancelDelete);
        $(document).on("keypress", onKeyPress);

        return false;
    });
});
```

The link works on the initial page load. However, the link is part of a partial view, and when I use ajax to reload the partial view, the link no longer works. It's as if the link between class="delete-link" and the javascript is no longer there.

Incidentaly, when I load the partial view in question, I do it this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: this.method,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        targetDiv.html(''); // Clear it out
        // Refresh the listDiv
        listDiv.load(listDiv.attr('data-source-href')); // This is where I get the partial list reloaded
    }
});
```

I thought that if I specify the onclick event in the link instead of relying on the dom/javascript linking it, it would work. So I tried this:

```
<a onclick="DeleteLink(this);" href="@Url.Action("_CustomFieldDelete", new {id = item.CustomFieldId})">Delete</a>

//... In my script.js file.
DeleteLink = function (link) {
    var deleteLink = $(link);
    deleteLink.hide();
    //... Remainder is exactly the same as $("a.delete-link").click(function () {
};
```

However, this does not work, I can walk through the javascript, so it's being called, but then the confirmButton reverts, or I get navigated to the route in the href. I'm still trying to figure that part out.

Maybe it's cause it's 5PM, maybe I'm missing something obvious... How can I get

```
$("a.delete-link").click(function () {
```

to work ever time, even from an ajax load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the answer is very simple. Element that you are binding the event to does no exist, so you have to bind it to one that exists in time of that binding. You can use the element's parent or the document object.

To bind events to dynamic content use this solution:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.delete-link', function (event) {
    // code code code
});
```